# Two different output file when run from PyCharm and Linux

Tags: python, file, pycharm

I have code that open a file, write to file and close the file:

```
file = open("test.lib", 'w')
file.write("aaaaaa\n")
file.write("bbbbbb\n")
file.close()
```

when I run the program from pycharm, the file content is correct:

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
```

But when I run it from the console, by run 'python my_program', the file content is wrong:

```
bbbbbb
aaaaaa
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me, but try this: `content = ['aaaaaa\n', 'bbbbbb\n']
file.writelines(content) 
file.close()`

Comment: Are you sure about the result, with your code? To me, it seems that your real code was more complex (asynchronous write, or maybe from different modules, or ..). But what if what you wrote is real, many programs will fail. Note: writing to console, stdout and stderr could be written in different moments (different cache)